# JQuery Menu - Select Item by Default

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to create a navigation structure on my web site. This structure is defined by the following code:

```
<ul id="theMenu"> 
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="Home" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Home</a></li>
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="About" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />About</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="Our Team" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Our Team</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="Our Company" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Our Process</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="Catalog" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Catalog</a> 
    <ul> 
     <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Men's Clothing</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Women's Cloting</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Kids Clothing</a></li> 
  </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li><a title="Contact Us" href="#" class="btm"><img alt="Contact Us" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
    $("#theMenu > li > a").click(function () {
      $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
  });
</script>
```

In some situations, I want to pre-select one of the menu items. Let's pretend that I wanted the "Catalog" menu pre-selected (expanded). How would I do this via JQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current markup something like

```
     $("img[alt=Catalog]").parent('a').click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/LLrrV/7/