# JQuery Navigating a ul tree

Tags: jquery

This is related, but not identical to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045630/jquery-menu-select-item-by-default). So I thought it made sense to start a new thread. I am using JQuery to create a navigation structure on my web site. This structure is defined by the following code:

```
<ul id="theMenu"> 
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="Home" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Home</a></li>
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="About" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />About</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="Our Team" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Our Team</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#"><img alt="Our Company" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Our Process</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li><a title="" href="#"><img alt="Catalog" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Catalog</a> 
    <ul> 
     <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Men's Clothing</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Women's Cloting</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/dot.png" class="subMenuHeader" />Kids Clothing</a></li> 
  </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li><a title="Contact Us" href="#" class="btm"><img alt="Contact Us" src="/dot.png" class="menuHeader" />Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
    $("#theMenu > li > a").click(function () {
      $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently, I'm calling "slideUp" on all of the  elements that is not the first one. Is there a way for me to call slideUp on all of them except for one? Currently, I have the name of the parent element at load time. For instance, when I get to the line that says "$("#theMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);", I may know that the 'Catalog' list should remain open. Is there a way to do this? Is there a way for me to loop through my items and say "If the image beside me doesn't have an 'Alt' of 'Catalog', then slideup? I know it seem like an odd question. But my UI is jerky without this approach.

Thank you so much for your help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited version:

```
$("#theMenu > li > a").each(function()
{
    var item = $(this);
    if($(this).find('img').attr('alt') != "Catalog")
    {
        $(this).siblings("ul").slideUp(1);
    }
});
```

Try that.

Comment: Hi True North Creative. It looks like this only runs when a user click's the menu item. I want to do what I described when the page initially loads. Essentially, I'm looking to replace the line that says "$("#theMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);" with some looping code that does what I described.

Comment: Ah, I'll change it - I thought you meant (with) what you've done

Comment: Hi true north creative. Thank you for trying. But it's not workign. It's throwing some obscure JavaScript error.

Comment: OK - changed it. Had to actually open it in a browser and see what you were trying to do :).  Let me know if that works.

Comment: What is the use of > in   '#theMenu > li > a'  ? can you please explain me. @TNC